# Как можно получить данные из сертификата .crt?

Tags: python, ssl, сертификат

Подскажите, как используя pyOpenSSL, получить данные из сертификата (имя организации, адрес и т.п)? Насколько я понял, надо использовать OpenSSL.crypto.X509Name.get_components. Найти пример мне не удалось, а самостоятельно решить задачу не смог.

[Пример сертификата](http://uakey.com.ua/files/download.php?file=1641073)

Comment: откуда сертификат берётся? Просто из файла? Похожий вопрос, если нужно получить данные для сертификата, используемого сервером, с которым установлено соединение: [How to get server's ssl certificate in a human readable form?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104623/1321)

Comment: [`x509.get_subject().get_components()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18806962/4279) работает для Вашего сертификата

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, все получилось. Вопросы, которые тоже помогли: [ссылка1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429770/how-to-read-an-untrusted-certificate-to-extract-informations-using-python) [ссылка2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689941/how-can-i-retrieve-the-tls-ssl-peer-certificate-of-a-remote-host-using-python)

Comment: `FILETYPE_PEM` (как показано в Ваших ссылках) не будет работать в этом случае. Используйте, `FILETYPE_ASN1`, как указано в [ссылке, которую я привёл выше](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18806962/4279). Если вы думаете что нашли ответ, то [опубликуйте его, чтобы помочь другим с похожей проблемой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Да, так и есть, использовал `FILETYPE_ASN1` `x509=OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, cert)`      `res = x509.get_subject().get_components()`       И перевод в utf-8 значений полей: `for i in range(0,len(res)): print(res[i][1].decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Вы можете [отредактировать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/463655/edit), чтобы код в комментариях не комкать. Хотя, если это ответ, то лучше конечно в виде ответа, когда вопрос откроется (если это не произойдёт за пару дней, то попробуйте [на Мету написать](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/))

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806962/simple-der-cert-parsing-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы без затруднений извлекать необходимую информацию из [x509 сертификата](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4) полезно иметь представление о [DER кодировке и его ASN.1 описании](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html), изложенном в [rfc 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#appendix-A).

Обычно работать со структурами данными, заданными через ASN.1, не очень удобно: бинарный формат, не нужная строгость, увеличивающая сложность без толку, для одних данных и игнорирование полезных ограничений в большинстве реализаций для других -- достаточно посмотреть как `DirectoryString` интерпретируется. На практике, некоторые поля в сертификате могут по-разному интерпретироваться разными инструментами. Даже для задач средней сложности приходится изучать исходный код, соответствующих библиотек, чтобы понять как добраться до желаемых данных в нужном формате.

В простых случаях, можно просто преобразовать в более человеческий формат нужный участок сертификата, например, чтобы прочитать [Subject](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.6) сертификата из файла и сконвертировать его в JSON формат, используя [`asn1crypto` модуль](https://github.com/wbond/asn1crypto):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import sys
from asn1crypto import x509  # $ pip install asn1crypto

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as der_file:
    cert = x509.Certificate.load(der_file.read()) # see cert.debug()
    json.dump(cert.subject.native, sys.stdout, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

`asn1crypto` это чистый Питон и не использует `openssl`. Интерфейс более приятный чем аналоги, но реализация не очень добротная, например, модуль ломается на Jython.

#### [pyOpenSSL](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/crypto.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import sys
from OpenSSL import crypto  # $ pip install pyopenssl

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as der_file:
    x509 = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, der_file.read())

json.dump({name.decode(): value.decode('utf-8')
           for name, value in x509.get_subject().get_components()},
          sys.stdout, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

[`pyOpenSSL`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL) сейчас наиболее используемая openssl обёртка для Питона.

#### [M2Crypto](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import json
import sys
from M2Crypto import X509

der_cert_filename = sys.argv[1]
cert = X509.load_cert(der_cert_filename, X509.FORMAT_DER)
x509name = cert.get_subject()
json.dump({nid: getattr(x509name, nid).decode('utf-8')
           for nid in x509name.nid if getattr(x509name, nid)},
          sys.stdout, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True)
```

`M2Crypto` библиотека первоначально была наиболее полной обёрткой для openssl. Реализация была долгое время заброшена. [Сейчас снова поддерживается.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto)

#### [`cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#loading-certificates)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import sys

from cryptography import x509  # $ pip install cryptography
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

oid2name = x509.oid._OID_NAMES
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as der_file:
    cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(der_file.read(),
                                          backend=default_backend())
    json.dump({oid2name.get(name.oid) or name.oid.dotted_string: name.value
               for name in cert.subject},
              sys.stdout, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

#### [`pyasn1`](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
from pyasn1.codec.der.decoder import decode  # $ pip install pyasn1
from pyasn1_modules import rfc2459  # $ pip install pyasn1_modules

OID = rfc2459.AttributeType
oid2name = {  # rfc 5280 (successor of rfc 2459)
    OID('2.5.4.3'): 'commonName',
    OID('2.5.4.5'): 'serialNumber',
    OID('2.5.4.6'): 'countryName',
    OID('2.5.4.7'): 'localityName',
    OID('2.5.4.8'): 'stateOrProvinceName',
    OID('2.5.4.9'): 'streetAddress',
    OID('2.5.4.10'): 'organizationName',
    OID('2.5.4.11'): 'organizationalUnitName',
    OID('2.5.4.17'): 'postalCode',
}
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as der_file:
    cert, rest = decode(der_file.read(), asn1Spec=rfc2459.Certificate())
    assert not rest  # file contains only the certificate
    rdnsequence, = cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']
    d = OrderedDict()
    for rdn, in rdnsequence:  # NOTE: rdn.prettyPrintType() is your friend
        comp, rest = decode(rdn['value'], asn1Spec=rfc2459.X520name())
        assert not rest
        assert comp.getName() == 'utf8String'
        d[oid2name[rdn['type']]] = bytes(comp['utf8String']).decode('utf-8')
    json.dump(d, sys.stdout, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

`pyasn1` находится в самом основании зависимостей и не использует C `openssl`. `pyasn1` работает на Python 2, Python 3, Pypy, Jython. Текущая реализация `pyOpenSSL` зависит от `cryptography`, которая зависит от `pyasn1` и C `openssl`.

Только первый пример (с asn1crypto) может поддерживать вложенные структуры без изменений в коде (`.native` вызывается рекурсивно и возвращает подходящие структуры данных, например, `collections.OrderedDict` в примере).

[Не всегда и не все строки обязаны быть `UTF8String` в сертификате](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.4).

Примеры показывают, что даже в простейшем случае, результаты (имена полей в данном случае) могут различаться для одного и того же ввода.

Также информацию можно получить в командной строке, с помощью [`openssl asn1parse`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/asn1parse.html):

```
$ openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in сертификат.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

Например при помощи модуля [pyOpenSSL](http://www.pyopenssl.org/en/0.15.1/api.html)