# Чтение ssl-сертификата из строки в base64 DER формате

Tags: python, python-2.x, ssl, openssl, сертификат

Как мне прочитать в `Python` содержимое `ssl`-сертификата, который представлен в виде типа `buffer` ? Мне нужно достать из него серийный номер.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как можно получить данные из сертификата .crt?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463655/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по [вашем ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574429/23044), `cert` у вас это base64 представление сертификата в DER кодировке (добавляя `BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE` строчки, вы превращаете это в PEM представление).

В таком случае, достаточно декодировать из base64, чтобы передать сертификат в функции, ожидающие DER формат, например, используя [`asn1crypto` пакет (чистый Питон, не использует openssl)](https://github.com/wbond/asn1crypto):

```
import base64
from asn1crypto import x509  # $ pip install asn1crypto

cert = x509.Certificate.load(base64.b64decode(base64_der))
print(cert.serial_number)
```

где `base64_der` это ваш сертификат, *«который представлен в виде типа buffer»*. Кроме `asn1crypto` вы ещё можете использовать и другие библиотеки, например: `pyOpenSSL`, `M2Crypto`, `cryptography`, `pyasn1`. См., [пример кода и основные отличия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464445/23044).

Альтернативно, можно наоборот обернуть `base64_der`, чтобы получить PEM представление:

```
import ssl

pem_string = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----' + base64_der + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
der_bytes = ssl.PEM_cert_to_DER_cert(pem_string)
cert = x509.Certificate.load(der_bytes)
print(cert.serial_number)
```

См. также [`asn1crypto.pem.detect()`](https://github.com/wbond/asn1crypto/blob/master/docs/pem.md).

Для быстрого хака, достаточно стандартной библиотеки:

```
import ssl

p = ssl._ssl._test_decode_cert(tmp_certificate_path)
print(p['serialNumber'])
```

где `tmp_certificate_path` это путь к PEM файлу из [вашего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574429/23044) и [`ssl._ssl._test_decode_cert()` это неофициальная функция из `_ssl.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c1a55d325e3cd4985974f12dbeb16722fce0e55d/Modules/_ssl.c#L1367-L1403), которая существует только для тестов (значит может исчезнуть, изменить поведение в любой момент).

---

Для сравнения (чтобы оценить удобство, предоставляемое библиотеками типа `asn1crypto`), вот код, который использует OpenSSL API напрямую через [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), чтобы получить серийный номер x509 сертификата из строки, содержащей DER представление, закодированное в base64 формат как одна строчка:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import contextlib
import ctypes.util
from ssl import SSLError

_ssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('ssl'))
BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL = 0x100 # bio.h

def get_serial_number_from_base64_der_oneline(base64_der):
    if isinstance(base64_der, str):
        base64_der = base64_der.encode('ascii', 'strict')
    with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
        bio = _ssl.BIO_new_mem_buf(base64_der, len(base64_der))
        stack.callback(_ssl.BIO_free, bio)
        b64 = _ssl.BIO_new(BIO_f_base64()) 
        stack.callback(_ssl.BIO_free, b64)
        _ssl.BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL) # oneline
        certificate = _ssl.d2i_X509_bio(_ssl.BIO_push(b64, bio), None)
        stack.callback(_ssl.X509_free, certificate)
        # get a memory buffer # from _ssl.c
        biobuf = _ssl.BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())
        stack.callback(_ssl.BIO_free_all, biobuf)
        serialNumber = _ssl.X509_get_serialNumber(certificate)
        _ssl.i2a_ASN1_INTEGER(biobuf, serialNumber)
        # should not exceed 20 octets, 160 bits, so buf is big enough
        buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(21) # char[21]
        size = _ssl.BIO_gets(biobuf, buf, len(buf)-1)
        if size <= 0:
            raise SSLError
        return buf[:size].decode()

# https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BIO_f_base64.html
# const BIO_METHOD *BIO_f_base64(void);
BIO_f_base64 = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))(("BIO_f_base64", _ssl))
BIO_s_mem = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))(("BIO_s_mem", _ssl))

def null_check(result, func, arguments):
    if not result:
        raise SSLError
    return result

for f in [BIO_f_base64, BIO_s_mem, _ssl.BIO_new_mem_buf, _ssl.BIO_new, _ssl.d2i_X509_bio]:
    f.errcheck = null_check
```

Алгоритм:

1. декодируется `base64` представление, используя `BIO_f_base64()`, получаем DER
2. DER превращаем во внутреннее представление, используя `d2i_X509_bio()`
3. `X509_get_serialNumber()` извлекает серийный номер как `ASN1_INTEGER`
4. `i2a_ASN1_INTEGER()` даёт серийный номер как число в ascii строке

Из-за отсутствия прототипов у некоторых функций (для краткости, пример и так длинный), код
вероятно может сломаться на платформах, где размеры указателя и целого
разные.

`ExitStack()` и `null_check` используются, чтобы ресурсы освободить в
случае ошибки. Так как используется C API, то приходится явно временем
жизни управлять.

Пример:

```
print(get_serial_number_from_base64_der_oneline(base64_der))
```

где `base64_der` та же строка что и в других примерах.

Comment: А как можно получить `skid` сертификата ?

Comment: @faoxis вероятно также как и серийного номера: посмотрите как поле обзывается для "Subject key identifier" в библиотеке, которую вы используете для чтения сертификата, и используете его (возможно вложенное). Подробнее в [связанном вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463655/23044)

Comment: я использую класс `x509.Certificate`. В нем есть поле `subject`, но это не похоже на `SKID`. Может я не там смотрю ?

Comment: Задал новый вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619087/Как-удалить-из-списка-словари-с-повторяющимся-полем/618913#618913

Answer (score 3):

Парсить руками - это, конечно, тупик. Разные форматы потребуют разных функций. Можно попробовать библиотеку [PyOpenSSL](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/crypto.html?#OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_serial_number). Я взял тестовый сертификат в формате PEM [отсюда](http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certexamples.htm).

```
import OpenSSL.crypto as crypto

CERT_PATH = "512b-rsa-example-cert.pem"

buf = open(CERT_PATH, "rb").read()

cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, buf)
print(cert.get_serial_number())

>>> 3578
```

Answer (score 1):

Пока что не придумал ничего лучше, чем это:

```
def _get_serial_from_certificate(cert):
    lines = []
    for i in range(0, len(cert), 64):
        lines.append(cert[i:i + 64])

    lines.insert(0, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----")
    lines.append("-----END CERTIFICATE-----")

    tmp_certificate_path = os.path.join(root, 'tmp', 'temp_certificate.cer')
    with open(tmp_certificate_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(lines))

    subject_text = check_output(['openssl', 'x509', '-in', tmp_certificate_path, '-serial'])
    return re.match(r'serial=(\w{32})', subject_text).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

В ответах не упоминалась библиотека ctypescrypto, которая показалась мне удобнейшей. X509 загружает любой сертификат, который поймет libcrypto (от openssl или аналога). Пример в 2 строки:

```
from ctypescrypto.x509 import X509

with open('/home/eri/Projects/rkn/provider.pem','rb') as f:
    cert=X509(f.read())
    print(cert.serial)
```

Чтоб прочитать ключик для ГОСТ добавить перед импортом.

```
from ctypescrypto.engine import Engine,set_default
set_default(Engine('gost'))
```