# Как узнать SKID сертификата?

Tags: python, ssl, сертификат

Использую библиотеки `ssl` и `asn1crypto`. Получаю объект типа `x509.Certificate` таким образом:

```
der_bytes = ssl.PEM_cert_to_DER_cert(pem_string)
cert = x509.Certificate.load(der_bytes)
```

Не могу найти у объекта `cert` поле `skid` или что-то вроде того.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как можно получить данные из сертификата .crt?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463655/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Subject key identifier" доступен в [`asn1crypto.x509`](https://github.com/wbond/asn1crypto), как `key_identifier` (в виде байт):

```
print(cert.key_identifier)
# b'\x1b\xe7J\xe5J,\xd3\xc4\x14\xc0\x05\xa8|6\xf7k\xc6\x1cbR'
```

Более традиционно это значение записывается в шестнадцатеричном виде через двоеточие:

```
import binascii

def to_hex_with_colon(bytestring):
    s = binascii.hexlify(bytestring).upper().decode()
    return ':'.join([s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)])


print(to_hex_with_colon(cert.key_identifier))
# -> 1B:E7:4A:E5:4A:2C:D3:C4:14:C0:05:A8:7C:36:F7:6B:C6:1C:62:52
```

Примеры приведены для [`server.crt` из urllib3](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shazow/urllib3/c0ce2c8ec800b571938807f15902b1dd52d0d6be/dummyserver/certs/server.crt):

```
from asn1crypto import pem, x509  # $ pip install asn1crypto

with open('server.crt', 'rb') as cert_file:
    der_bytes = cert_file.read()
    if pem.detect(der_bytes):
        _, _, der_bytes = pem.unarmor(der_bytes)
    cert = x509.Certificate.load(der_bytes)  # cert.debug()
```