# Получение невалидного SSL-сертификата через модуль ssl в читаемом виде

Tags: python, ssl, сертификат

Для получения валидного сертификата работает такой код (если сменить домен):

```
import ssl, socket

hostname = 'v5.eprica.ru'
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
s = ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=hostname)
s.connect((hostname, 443))
cert = s.getpeercert()

print(cert)
```

В случае невалидного сертификата (как с этим доменом) - исключение. Как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить сертификат как строку в PEM формате:

```
import ssl

pem_string = ssl.get_server_certificate((host, port))
```

Чтобы декодировать PEM строку, можно `asn1crypto` модуль использовать:

```
from asn1crypto import pem, x509  # $ pip install asn1crypto

der_bytes = ssl.PEM_cert_to_DER_cert(pem_string)
cert = x509.Certificate.load(der_bytes)
```

Можно обращаться к индивидуальным атрибутам:

```
>>> cert.issuer.native
OrderedDict([('country_name', 'GB'), ('state_or_province_name', 'Greater Manchester'), ('locality_name', 'Salford'), ('organization_name', 'COMODO CA Limited'), ('common_name', 'COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA')])
```

Так и всё сразу в словарь превратить: `cert.native` (для отладки: `cert.debug()`).

В качестве хака, можно `cert = ssl._ssl._test_decode_cert('cert.pem')` использовать, чтобы `pem_string` декодировать (если `pem_string` сохранена в `cert.pem` файл).

См. также варианты, использующие другие библиотеки, и для сравнения варианты с использованием `ctypes`:

- [Как можно получить данные из сертификата .crt?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463655/23044)
- [Чтение ssl-сертификата из строки в base64 DER формате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/574384/23044)

Comment: Эх, хак не сработал: ssl.SSLError: Error decoding PEM-encoded file придется, значит, дополнительные модули ставить...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вы имя файла передали или содержимое? asn1crypto это чистый Питон—проблем с установкой быть не должно

Comment: Да, имя файла с сертификатом.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов какая версия Питона? Чему `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` равно? Визуально `'-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` видно в файле? Можете выложить, если хотите pem файл.

Comment: Сертификат более чем корректный, даже серт Яндекса так не хочет есть. Версии определенно несвежие, но оно того уже не стоит. В любом случае спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: от yandex понимает сертификат (проверял на телефоне с `OpenSSL 1.0.2f 28 Jan 2016`)

Comment: Эт у меня глаз замылился и не увидел проблем с записью файла. Работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В читаемом виде автоматически можно получить только сертификаты, прошедшие валидацию. Невалидные же сертификаты надо брать в бинарном виде (DEM), а затем отдельно их парсить.

Код получения сертификата в PEM формате:

```
import ssl, socket

hostname = 'v5.eprica.ru'
conn = socket.create_connection((hostname, 443))
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(conn)
cert = sock.getpeercert(True)
cert = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(cert)
print(cert)
```

Как получить информацию из PEM сертификата можно подсмотреть тут: [How can I decode a SSL certificate using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899247)

Comment: А где-то в документации есть про то, что можно в нормальном виде получить только валидный серт?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Да, написано в доках к [`getpeercert()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert).