# С помощью какой библиотеки можно прочитать .cer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрых суток.
С помощью какой библиотеки можно прочитать файл .cer?
Пробовал с помощью pem, но вернуло пустой список.

Comment: Наверное, pycrypto сможет

Comment: для чтения файла (с любым именем) никаких (дополнительных) библиотек не требуется. вас, вероятно, интересует интерпретация какого-то особого содержимого файла? ну так оно (содержимое) с именем файла абсолютно никак не связано (по крайней мере в хоть сколько-то популярных современных операционных системах).

Comment: @alexander barakin, естественно меня интересует не процесс чтения файла, а процесс чтения сертификата.

Comment: так напишите это прямо в тексте вопроса.

Comment: Кажется пакет pyasn1 умеет декодировать x.509

Comment: Связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463655/23044