# python, сравнение списков без учета регистров, исправление кодировки

Tags: python, кодировка, python-2.x, списки

Всем привет.
Есть 2 списка

```
massive=[['cn=Андрей', 'ou=Masters', 'o=lab2', '0b1dwe8065eff78ad92771ef78cc076c'],['cn=Barma', 'ou=Masters', 'o=lab2', '0b1dc48065eff78ad92771ef78cdfgdf']]

list1=[['CN=Андрей', 'OU=Masters', 'O=lab2', '0b1dwe8065eff78ad92771ef78cc076c'],['CN=Barmad', 'OU=Masters', 'O=lab2', 'fb1dc48065eff78ad92771ef78cdfgdf']]
```

нужно вывести разницу первого списка со вторым

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def change (massive,list1):
    to_del=[]
    to_add=[]    
    for num in list1:
        if num not in massive:
            to_del.append(num)
    for num in massive:
        if num not in list1:
            to_add.append(num)     
    return to_add,to_del

to_add,to_del=change(massive,list1)
print to_add
print '\n'
print to_del
```

но вместо этого он выводит все содержимое списков потому что разные регистры в начале каждой записи.

```
[['cn=\xd0\x90\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9', 'ou=Masters', 'o=lab2', '0b1dwe8065eff78ad92771ef78cc076c'], ['cn=Barma', 'ou=Masters', 'o=lab2', '0b1dc48065eff78ad92771ef78cdfgdf']]

[['CN=\xd0\x90\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9', 'OU=Masters', 'O=lab2', '0b1dwe8065eff78ad92771ef78cc076c'], ['CN=Barmad', 'OU=Masters', 'O=lab2', 'fb1dc48065eff78ad92771ef78cdfgdf']]
```

Вопрос первый, как сравнить эти списки без учета регистров?
вопрос второй как сделать человеческое отображение русских символов

Comment: а почему питон2, а не 3? :) И напишите в вопросе какой ожидаемый результат должен будет получиться

Comment: попробуйте использовать готовые библиотеки для получения данных из ssl сертификатов [Как можно получить данные из сертификата .crt?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463655/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
def change(items_1, items_2):
    to_ulower = lambda x: x.decode('utf-8').lower()

    # Для приведения элементов в нижний регистр
    items_1 = [list(map(to_ulower, sub_list)) for sub_list in items_1]
    items_2 = [list(map(to_ulower, sub_list)) for sub_list in items_2]

    to_del = [num for num in items_1 if num not in items_2]
    to_add = [num for num in items_2 if num not in items_1]

    return to_add, to_del


items_1 = [['cn=Андрей', 'ou=Masters', 'o=lab2', '0b1dwe8065eff78ad92771ef78cc076c'], ['cn=Barma', 'ou=Masters', 'o=lab2', '0b1dc48065eff78ad92771ef78cdfgdf']]
items_2 = [['CN=Андрей', 'OU=Masters', 'O=lab2', '0b1dwe8065eff78ad92771ef78cc076c'], ['CN=Barmad', 'OU=Masters', 'O=lab2', 'fb1dc48065eff78ad92771ef78cdfgdf']]

to_add, to_del = change(items_1, items_2)
print 'to_add: %s' % (to_add,)
print 'to_del: %s' % (to_del,)
```

Результат:

```
to_add: [['cn=barmad', 'ou=masters', 'o=lab2', 'fb1dc48065eff78ad92771ef78cdfgdf']]
to_del: [['cn=barma', 'ou=masters', 'o=lab2', '0b1dc48065eff78ad92771ef78cdfgdf']]
```

Comment: это не будет работать: `"Андрей".lower() != "андрей"` [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/319426/4279)

Comment: А использовать вместо lower -- casefold?

Comment: метка у вопроса [tag:python-2.x] Начать стоит с использования unicode для текста, а где остановиться — это от задачи зависит.

Comment: @jfs, а теперь?

Comment: будет работать, но в unicode на границе, где данные приходят, лучше преобразовывать.